Virtual paths broken?
So, I have been having a recurring problem with Windows, thought it was a Windows 10 issue, upgraded to 11, and suddenly realized it still existed, Shows unity calling a package with the "g" letter added to its path
It could be seen here that, the unity editor is calling to a package with nearly the correct path, but the added g in front breaks it, same here. VS code calls node.exe but with g in the path VS code is trying to call node.exe, but a g is added in front. If it works, it looks for its dependencies, which have a "g" in their path. Since there is no folder with "g," it stops working. Simply analogy with games: The game path is: D:\Games\Game1 Game data paths are: D:\Games\Game1\Data I open its .exe it says there should be a "data" Folder beside the executable file
I raised a Ticket at Microsoft support, and they gave me a few options to do.
I did most of them (environment variables, re-installs, repairs, checks, etc.), but I don't have any idea what one of them is or how to even diagnose it. Namely virtual paths in the registry
Edit Solution Solved, it is a malware, try installing different AVs and run root level and all files scans.
I won't be deleting this question for others who have the same problem and thought it was a broken path.

Check whether the "g*.exe" files themselves exist, like that C:\Program Files\nodejs\gnode.exe - they may be set as hidden or system files (try enabling View > hidden items in explorer). Googling for "windows adding g to exe name" shows many people getting this behavior from a virus that seems to try and insert/disguise itself this way. It may be best to reset the PC entirely after backing up your data (be careful to exclude affected files though)

@Cpt.Whale now that is researched a bit on my PC... the compressed backups on my PC has different sizes of the .exe files, but the moment it has that "g", it switches to 526/228 kb.... seems like i will have to do a full scan using multiple programs...
i just did a fresh install of windows and programs ;-;

I guess it is indeed a malware issue, I have had windows defender active and still got that malware, changed, installed malware byte then switched to avast, did a full scan, all files but zip, rar, iso, did a root scan, and got the issue fixed, i will leave the the post as is, so people with the same issue who thought it was a path problem at first, might find a solution here
